# Inheritance from recursive template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, recursion

I'm trying to implement some kind of multi-dimensional arrays thanks to recursive templates.

My template class has the structure below:

```
template< typename T, unsigned int D >
class MultiArray
{
public:
    MultiArray();

protected:
    std::vector< MultiArray< T, D - 1 > > VecSubarrays;
};

template< typename T >
class MultiArray< T, 0 >
{
public:
    MultiArray();

protected:
    T Item;
};
```

with some accessors, modifiers, etc.

I wanted to "specialize" this template class with `T = double`, and add some specific features, like operator overloading (+, -, +=, -=).

So I created this template class:

```
template< unsigned int D >
class MultiArrayDouble: public MultiArray< double, D >
{
public:
    MultiArrayDouble();

    template< unsigned int E >
        MultiArrayDouble< D >& operator+=(MultiArrayDouble< E > const& A_MAD);
    MultiArrayDouble< D >& operator+=(MultiArrayDouble< 0 > const& A_MAD);
};
```

where I overloaded `operator+=` (edit: see below for the implementation).

But this structure hasn't the behavior I expect. I believed that the subarrays of a `MultiArrayDouble< D >` object were just `MultiArrayDouble< D - 1 >`. But I coded recursively `operator+=`, and the compiler said :

```
error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'MultiArray<double, 1u>' and 'const MultiArray<double, 1u>')
```

In fact, the subarrays of a `MultiArrayDouble< D >` object are `MultiArray< double, D - 1 >`, where `operator+=` isn't overloaded.

I think I can handle the problem with some cast from `MultiArray< double, D >` to `MultiArrayDouble< D >`, but I am looking for an elegant solution.

I thought I could specify as template parameter the subarrays type, like that:

```
template< typename T, unsigned int D, template< typename, unsigned int, typename > typename U >
class MultiArray
{
public:
    MultiArray();

protected:
    std::vector< U< T, D - 1, ??? > > VecSubarrays;
};
```

and replace `U` by `MultiArray` for general arrays, or `MultiArrayDouble` for double arrays. But I cannot write the exact subarray type (look at the "???")…

Are there standard solutions to this problem ? Should I avoid inheritance from recursive template classes ?

Thank you.

**edit**:

Implementation of `operator+=`:

```
template< unsigned int D >
template< unsigned int E >
MultiArrayDouble< D >& MultiArrayDouble< D >::operator+=(MultiArrayDouble< E > const& A_MAD)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < this->Length() ; i++)
    {
        (*this)[i] += A_MAD[i];
    }
    return (*this);
}

template< unsigned int D >
MultiArrayDouble< D >& MultiArrayDouble< D >::operator+=(MultiArrayDouble< 0 > const& A_MAD)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < this->Length() ; i++)
    {
        (*this)[i] += A_MAD;
    }
    return (*this);
}

template<  >
MultiArrayDouble< 0 >& MultiArrayDouble< 0 >::operator+=(MultiArrayDouble< 0 > const& A_MAD)
{
    (*this) += A_MAD;
    return (*this);
}
```

Notes:

- the operator `operator[](unsigned int i)` returns the i-th subarray, i.e. `VecSubarrays[i]`;
- I've implemented implicit cast from `MultiArray< T, 0 >` to `T&`.

Comment: Can you show your code for the recursive `operator+=`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a specific class `MultiArryDouble` that inherits from `MultiArray`, I would rather use template specification mechanism. Specifying `MultiArray<double, D>` would be a better approach.

One drawback is that you would have to repeat the whole class.

Why not have the `operator+=` defined in `MultiArray`? That way, it would be defined for every `T` where `operator+=` is defined. And if you want specific behaviour, you could use a static helper class function, where you specialize the behaviour of the operator for each data type.

Comment: In fact, I didn't choose template specification to avoid repetitions… And I think I don't need any helper class function with `T = double`.

Comment: Well, what about my second solution (last paragraph)? I think it would serve your purposes. You just define `operator+=` inside the `MultiArray`, with a default implementation. However, if you want a specific behaviour for one `T`, you'll have to have `operator+=` call a helper struct, that you can specify to have the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it works, but it's not very satisfying if I want to have a class MultiArrayDouble with its specific functions.

Comment: How about having the operator work on any `MultiArray<double, N>` instead of `MultiArrayDouble` ?